# error using limit in codeignitier

Tags: codeigniter

What is my error problem?

```
function get_datatables1()
{       
    $tSQL = "select a.Kode, c.nama as Ruangan, d.nama as Kelas, b.nama as Kamar, a.jumlah as JumlahTT, a.sisa as SisaTT, a.Tarif, a.Deskripsi, a.Gambar from TMTrfTindakan a inner join TMTrfLayanan b on a.kodelayanan = b.kode inner join TMTrfKelompok c on b.kodekelompok = c.kode inner join TMTrfKelas d on a.kodekelas = d.kode where c.KodeKlasifikasi = 2";
    $query = $this->db->query($tSQL);
    //  $this->kamar->count_filtered1()
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->query($tSQL)->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->query($tSQL);
    return $query->result();
}
```

error says:

> Severity: Error
>
> Message:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_result::limit()

Comment: thanks for correction jrbedard

Answer (score 0):

Your query will run on when excecuting `$this->db->query($tSQL)`. you can't add limit to query result.

Try using codeigniter [active record](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)

```
function get_datatables1()
{  
    $this->db->select('a.Kode, c.nama as Ruangan, d.nama as Kelas, b.nama as Kamar, a.jumlah as JumlahTT, a.sisa as SisaTT, a.Tarif, a.Deskripsi, a.Gambar');
    $this->db->from('TMTrfTindakan a');
    $this->db->join('TMTrfLayanan b', 'a.kodelayanan = b.kode', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('TMTrfKelompok c', ' b.kodekelompok = c.kode', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('TMTrfKelas d', 'a.kodekelas = d.kode', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('c.KodeKlasifikasi', 2); 
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Also you can do this without active record

```
function get_datatables1()
{       
    $tSQL = "select a.Kode, c.nama as Ruangan, d.nama as Kelas, b.nama as Kamar, a.jumlah as JumlahTT, a.sisa as SisaTT, a.Tarif, a.Deskripsi, a.Gambar from TMTrfTindakan a inner join TMTrfLayanan b on a.kodelayanan = b.kode inner join TMTrfKelompok c on b.kodekelompok = c.kode inner join TMTrfKelas d on a.kodekelas = d.kode where c.KodeKlasifikasi = 2";

    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $tSQL .= 'limit ' . $_POST['length'] . ' offset ' . $_POST['start'];

    $query = $this->db->query($tSQL);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: hi noufalcep need help again

Comment: my command sql like this :
select a.norm, b.nama as pasien, b.alamat, c.tanggal, c.tanggal1, f.jumlah, f.biaya from TTKunjungan a inner join TMPasien b on A.norm = b.norm inner join TTKunjunganDetail c on A.Kode = c.kodekunjungan inner join TMTrfTindakan d on c.kodetindakan = d.Kode inner join TMTrfLayanan e on d.kodelayanan = e.Kode left join (select kodett, sum(jumlah) as jumlah, sum(biaya) as biaya from TTKunjunganDetail where kodett is not null group by kodett) f on  c.Kode = F.kodett Where e.kodeklasifikasi = 2 and c.tanggal1 is null and c.kodett is null and c.kodetindakan = '$Kode'

Comment: For using subqueries better use `$this->db->query('your query');` instead of active records.

Comment: thanks noufalcep but that not support $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);

Comment: You can add limit and offset on your query without active record.. `your query LIMIT ' . $_POST['length'] . ' OFFSET ' . $_POST['start'] `.   I have updated my answer with alternate solution

Comment: noufalcep thanks before ill try ASAP, do u have example crud but using innerjoint with this command $this->db->query('your query'); cause i have trouble using search column and sort order

Comment: I dont have an example. if you have any issue in your try, post here. you will get help.. For your requirement like seach , sort and pagination.. better user Data Tables.. It will save some effort.. I found one datatable library for codeigniter from google.. I hope this will help you--https://github.com/zepernick/Codeigniter-DataTables

Comment: hi noufalcep can u help me for data record with sql command like this select a.norm, a.name, a.address + ' NUMBER ' + a.number + ' POBOX ' + a.pobox + ', ' + b.name + ', ' + c.name as address, a.dob, a.sex
from tmnama a inner join tmcountry b on a.kodevillage = b.kode inner join tmcountry c on b.kodeid = c.kode
where a.name like '%name %' thanks before

Comment: Use concat function for combine coloumns. `select a.norm, a.name, concat(a.address , ' NUMBER ',a.number,' POBOX ',a.pobox,', ',b.name,', ',c.name) as address, a.dob, a.sex from tmnama a inner join tmcountry b on a.kodevillage = b.kode inner join tmcountry c on b.kodeid = c.kode where a.name like '%name %'`

Comment: if im using concat my search, filter, and sorting in datatable not working

Comment: no error but search, filter and sorting not function

draw"4"
recordsTotal11787
recordsFiltered2
data[10]

Comment: actually data[2] not [10]

Comment: Its not because of concat, i think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: yes ur right the problem before select using " im using '